# Why am I getting a syntax error while running SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, syntax, syntax-error

I am new to PHP and SQL and trying run a code, which has run into a problem. Connected the SQL, included the PHP files and was working fine.

However, the moment I added the SQL query, I am getting an error

> syntax error, unexpected token". Unexpected 'Name'. Expected ';'.intelephense(1001)

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
include 'partials/_header.php';
include 'partials/_dbconnect.php';
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE category_id=1;
?>
```

Comment: You cant just put SQL in PHP. You need to create SQL  as a string, then execute that string with a db driver.

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. `The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the correct way to run a query in PHP

`partials/_dbconnect.php`:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

the code

```
<?php
include 'partials/_header.php';
include 'partials/_dbconnect.php';

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10");
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
```

Comment: When claiming "this is a correct way", make sure your code at least conforms to the example from the PHP manual

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah I will take care from now

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution in phpMyAdmin.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE category_id=1;";
```

Comment: This is PHP, not PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Oh, right. I just meant that I found the solution in phpMyAdmin where it says "Create PHP code". I clicked on it and found this.